Understanding the definition of $n$-th iterate of a transition kernel
I recently came across the  definition of the transition kernel for a continuous state space, which is defined recursively as follows:
\begin{aligned} & P^{(1)}(x, A)=P(x, A) \\ & P^{(n)}(x, A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} P^{(n-1)}(x, d y) P(y, A)\end{aligned}
Does anyone know how this definition is justified? I think it has to be a consequence of the markov property, but I don't quite see how(I'm very new to this level of math).
\begin{aligned}
P^{(2)}(x, A) & :=P\left(X_2 \in A \mid X_0=x\right) \\
& =\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} P\left(X_1=x_1 \mid X_0=x\right) P\left(X_2 \in A \mid X_1=x_1, X_0=x\right) d x_1 \text { [law of total probability] } \\
& =\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} P\left(X_1=x_1 \mid X_0=x\right) P\left(X_2 \in A \mid X_1=x_1\right) d x_1 \quad \text { [memoryless property] } \\
& =\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} P\left(x, \mathrm{dx}_1\right) P\left(x_1, A\right)
\end{aligned}
My thinking was that this would generalize, but I'm not sure if what I've written is correct.

Work out what the integral means for a discrete space with $d=1.$

@whuber Ok, so my understanding is that in this case, sums simply replace integrals:
\begin{aligned}
& P^{(2)}(x, A)=P\left(X_2 \in A \mid X_0=x\right) \
& =\sum_{x_1} P\left(X_1=x_1 \mid X_0=x\right) P\left(X_2 \in A \mid X_1=x_1, X_0=x\right) \
& =\sum_{x_1} P\left(X_1=x_1 \mid X_0=x\right) P\left(X_2 \in A \mid X_1=x_1\right) \quad \text { (Markov property) } \
& =\sum_{x_1} P\left(x, x_1\right) P\left(x_1, A\right)
\end{aligned}

So: all you have to do now is verify that the algebraic rules you employed in that derivation apply to multidimensional integrals.  That comes down to basic properties of integration.

I see, thank you! Unless I'm missing something glaring, that means that the answer I wrote down is correct, no?
